# STM32F0 - How long do timers take to set count value?

Tags: c, timer, stm32, interrupt

I've got an issue with STM32F0 timers. I'm doing everything register level and am disabling a timer and zeroing the count. After this I re-enable external interrupts and restart the timer on receipt of an edge.
It seems though that it the interrupt happens very soon after the count has been written, the zeroing does not take place.

I'm wondering if there is a delay when writing to the counter. I wonder if there would have to be at least one pre-scaled clock cycle?

Comment: Maybe you didn't clear some flag? It would be easier to answer if you could post a code sample.

Comment: You do not need to dsable or reset the timer. You need only register reload if you change shadowed register (or preloaded)